# DL - Link to a folder in another document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, links

I've got 2 document libraries. One contains forms that the organisation is using (organised in relevant folders). The other document library contains folders with names of departments. On the one hand, I'd like all forms to be in one place (hence a separate document library). On the other hand, I'd like each user to have access to their relevant forms within their deprtment folder (even just as a read only option). So I thought that within the departments folders, I'd create a shortcut/link to the corresponding folder in the forms document library. Any way of doing it?

What I have tried was going to the library settings=>Advanced Settings=>Allow management of content types and added a Link to a document. The problem is that then (other options disappear from the 'New' button drop down menu (excel, powerpoint, etc).

This is all in a browser.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

1.You could create links for forms in the folders with names of departments.

Go to document library modern experience, click add link.

[image]

2.Click "Edit new menu", choose content type.

[image]